# How do I insert a randomly generated variable into an array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have generated a number and sent it to a text box. Now I want to save that number for later use. Arrays seem (to my very limited knowledge) to be the place to keep data you wish to access later on. How do I do this?

my code so far:

```
roll_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, rollDice);
function rollDice (Event:MouseEvent):void{
    var die1:uint = Math.floor (Math.random()* 6) + 1;
    var die2:uint = Math.floor (Math.random()* 6) + 1;

    die1_txt.text = die1.toString();
    die2_txt.text = die2.toString();


    sec1_txt.text = (die1 + die2).toString();

}
```

I want to add the result in "sec1_txt.text" to an array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
var myArray:Array = new Array();

myArray.push(die1 + die2)
```

You can also use a Vector that is a typized (of uint) array.

Comment: Thanks, I used what you said & it worked, then I tried it with a map:Object instead. This seemed better for getting the result value out into a new text box without an 'undefined' error.